# How to write the following windows batch script in mac and linux counterparts?

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I am trying to launch a Java application using the JRE in the same folder.

The windows batch script was as :

```
"jre\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "main.jar";
```

How would you create a similar double clickable bash script that works on Mac and Linux?

Comment: I  should probably point out that this particular batch script relies on the pwd being the application's root. You may want to use "%~dp0\jre\bin\javaw.exe" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too different:

```
#!/bin/bash

jre/bin/javaw -jar main.jar
```

But most Linux distributions *do not* allow you to run scripts via double click. You have to open them via Terminal:

```
blender ~ $ bash ./script.sh
```

Comment: If you `chmod 755 script.sh` you can do away with the `bash` in the command.

Comment: I usually do `chmod +x script.sh`, but as I am lazy, I just press the up arrow until I get back to `bash ./script.sh`...

Comment: Yay lazy! For me, it's `^Rscr` and hope the history makes it easy to find.

Comment: Also `chmod a+x script.sh` so it can be executed directly.  And it's been a while since I've used the mouse for anything but switching focus between monitors, but it at least used to be that double-clicking an executable shell script would get you a prompt to run or edit in most distributions I used.

Comment: Didn't know about that one. Thanks. As for the click execution, that's dependent upon the file manager if I'm not mistaken. Thunar *can* do this, but I prefer to see debug output. Nautilus and PCManFM give prompts. As for the other FMs, I have no idea.

Comment: Mac uses the `bash` shell, as do most Linux distributions. As long as your binary is made for Mac OS X, that shell file should run fine across Mac and Linux.

Comment: @Blender, would it be able to find the `jre/bin/javaw` in the same directory as the `.sh` file? or is there some `$CURRENTDIR` I need to add?

Comment: No, when you run `foo/bar`, it searches for `foo/` in the current folder.